# React localStorage - Browser Console

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am having a problem about redirecting user when they are authenticated. It is fine when I click the login button, and the token stored on the localStorage. However, when I go to the browser console, and input the

> localStorage.setItem('token', test);

I am enable to render the MainComponent, which is I don't want to happen.

I have this sample code

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
    const authenticated = localStorage.getItem('token')
    return authenticated
}

function MainHelper(){
    const history = useHistory()
    const [isAuth, setAuth] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const token = isAuthenticated()
        if(!token){
            history.push('/login')
        }else{
            setAuth(true)
        }
    }, [isAuth, history])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {isAuth === true
            ? <MainComponent />
            : null
            }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: You should not rely on user side token alone. You should make a server request and validate the authenticity of the token and then allow the user to go to the main app. It may worth looking into JWT.

Comment: please add sample code in codesandbox for debugging is great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an API call and check the token for validating the first time.

```
if(!token){
  history.push('/login')
}else {
  fetch('your/token/validation/link', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }}).then(() => setAuth(true))
    .catch((err) => {
         localStorage.removeItem('token');
         history.push('/login');
    })
}
```

Comment: On the catch exception, i also have to clear to localStorage to prevent infinite rendering. Thank you. This solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a server storage: (Example: firebase)
It is easy to use with js just check (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

And that server must contain the all users and after isAuth is change check if the server storage contain that token

This link will help setup your database on firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)